# Dynamic Masterpage in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a radiobuttonlist in both masterpage like below.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMenuType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblMenuType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Horizontal Menu" Value="Horizontal"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Vertical Menu" Value="Vertical"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want as per the radiobutton selected for menu style, according to that masterpage will be changed dynamically.

What should I write in both masterpage and content page.

Thanks in advance.